# Error al agregar un listener en MapView.AnimatedRegion

Tags: react-native, expo

Al agregar un listener a MapView.AnimatedRegion lo agrega bien, lo ejecuta bien pero tira un error, el error dice que al listener le estoy pasando una instancia de un objeto pero le estoy pasando directamente una funcion (ver ejemplo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {AnimatedRegion} from 'react-native-maps';

export default class Test extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        const region = new AnimatedRegion({
            "latitude": -33.07204,
            "latitudeDelta": 0.01,
            "longitude": -68.98632,
            "longitudeDelta": 0.005622188905547227,
        });

        this.state = {
            coordinate: region
        };

        const listener = region.addListener((value) => {
            console.log(value);
        });

        console.log('id : ', listener);

    }

    async componentDidMount() {


        const duration = 5000;

        const coord = {
            "latitude": -33.07350,
            "latitudeDelta": 0.01,
            "longitude": -68.98632,
            "longitudeDelta": 0.005622188905547227,
        };

        this.state.coordinate.timing({
            ...coord,
            duration
        }).start();


    }


    render() {

        const {coordinate} = this.state;

        return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text>test...</Text>
            <MapView
                style={{flex: 1}}
                initialRegion={{
                    "latitude": -33.07204,
                    "latitudeDelta": 0.01,
                    "longitude": -68.98632,
                    "longitudeDelta": 0.005622188905547227,
                }}
            >
                <MapView.Marker.Animated
                    title={'tirulo'}
                    description={'description'}
                    coordinate={coordinate}
                />
            </MapView>

        </View>;
    }
}
```

mensaje:

```
this._listeners[n] is not a function. (In 'this._listeners[n]({value:t})', 'this._listeners[n]' is an instance of Object)
```

este es el Snack de ejemplo que tira el mismo error
https://snack.expo.io/@bykomarg/animatedregion

tambien cree un issue en react-native
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25224

el codigo funciona bien pero tira ese error, como puedo hacer para que no muestre el error arriba del mapa?

estoy usando expo sdk 33.0.0
hice la migracion de la app segun este documento
https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v33-0-0-is-now-available-52d1c99dfe4c

Answer (score 0):

En que momento te manda el error? copie el codigo y se ejecuta bien, la animacion tambien la hace ..
testeado con react native 0.58 y emulador ios 12.1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien me hace el debug del value

Comment: gracias por el test yo estoy usando expo sdk 33.0.0 .. es donde tira el error